# CLion bind shortcut to run command in terminal

Tags: c++, intellij-idea, build, keyboard-shortcuts, clion

I currently have a setup which can compile and run the currently focused file tab through a shortcut. I achieve this through the External Tool feature in which I assigned a custom bash file with a couple of commands to that keypress.

But this causes the output in the Run tab to clear each time I run my code. I want to preserve the output. This can be done if the bash file that I run through the External Tools can instead run as a command in the terminal when I press the shortcut.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Run tab will remain if you uncheck the "Open console for output" in the External tool configuration window. It won't open the tool's output then, though.